# Чем отличается -child от -of-type?

Tags: css, css3

Пытался понять их различия, но так и не понял, зачем их использовать. Например, `li:nth-child(odd)` и `li:nth-of-type(odd)`. В чём суть?

Comment: Первый выбирает все нечетные потомки не важно какой они селектор имеют. Второй берет все нечетные, но с селектором определенного типа. Т.е. если бы между ваших `li` были другие элементы он бы их не учитывал в счете(здесь ситуации не может быть такой, потому что `ul` или `ol` могут содержать только `li`). (первая ссылка в гугле, 2 слова нежели здесь 10+)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предположим, что у вас такая разметка:

```
<section>
   <h1>Words</h1>
   <p>Little</p>
   <p>Piggy</p>    <!-- Нужен этот элемент -->
</section>
```

Вариант `p:nth-of-type(2) { color: red; }` будет выбирать второй параграф одного родителя. И сработает правильно.

Вариант  `p:nth-child(2) { color: red; }` будет выбирать второй элемент одного родителя, и срабатывать если он является параграфом.
В данном случае выберется `<p>Little</p>` что неправильно.